# Results after Running LoRaEnergySim Simulator

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, simulation

After spending a while in searching for a simulator that simulates LoRa with the Adaptive Data Rate (ADR) algorithm at the same time is written using python, I found LoRaEnergySim
[(Webpage of the LoRaEnergySim on Github)](https://github.com/GillesC/LoRaEnergySim)
.

I ran the simulator, but when I viewed the results, I got the results like in the image.

Any clue here would be much much much appreciated.
[image: Results file obtained after running the simulation]

Comment: Are you asking why there are red stripes in the image? What did you expect to get instead? Are you sure that you are supposed to view the results in a text editor and not in a different application?